# Assign command's return code to variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I have this simple (even silly :) problem: Inside a bash script, I'm trying to store a command's return code to a variable using `S?`, so as to use it later in the script, but `S?` is stored literally as S? .
I run this test bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "trying to store this command's return code. it should be 0"
rtrn_code=S?
echo $rtrn_code
```

but instead of getting 0 (success return code) I get S? :

```
trying to store this command return code. it should be 0
S?
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: changue S for ``$``

Comment: Gardro, in bash all variable references begin with the `$` symbol. The `?` is simply a special variable in bash holding the return value from the previous command. So in order to (de)reference the value it holds you must precede it with the `$` sign -- `$?`. The downvotes (not mine) are simply a reflection that before asking here, you are supposed to use diligence to find the answer yourself. This being a fundamental bash-101 issue -- you are going to receive some...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `$?` and not `S?`.

```
rtrn_code=$?
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the last executed command can be accessed using `$?`. Replace `S?` to `$?` in your script.